# How to keep a window from overlapping into another workspace?

Tags: 11.04, compiz, workspaces

It's annoying to me how if a window is even a couple pixels off the right edge of my screen, when I switch to that right workspace, the system thinks that the window is there.  The unity launcher bar gets hidden because of it and switching to that window keeps you on the current workspace where you can't even see the window cause it's only a couple pixels.

KDE seems to do this much better where when you switch to another workspace, the window just isn't there. But well I don't want KDE.  Any way of getting that same behavior without the switch?

Edit:
[image: Chromium appears both on workspaces on the top right and bottom right]

Comment: I would really like to see this option being implemented in Unity somehow. Anything we can do to make this happens?

Comment: I just tried out Gnome shell and windows don't overlap workspaces there either.

Comment: This really needs to be fixed, according to me, it's a completely useless feature. Also, they should add "Show Windows" in desktop grid, like KDE does

Comment: similar post in case a solution ever comes. 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/218771/how-to-stop-windows-from-moving-past-the-edge-of-a-workspace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There doesn't seem to exist an option to do that in Compiz.

You can install the *CompizConfig Settings Manager* (package `compizconfig-settings-manager`, program `ccsm`) and raise the *Edge Resistance Distance* in the *Snap Window* plugin options in the *Window Management* section:

[image]

This will help to prevent pushing a window outside of the screen. However, if you move the window too fast it won't be triggered, so it's no optimal solution.

Maybe this issue is worth a mail to the [Ayatana mailing list](https://launchpad.net/~ayatana)? :-)

Comment: Perhaps this helped in the past, but as of 12.04 changing the edge resistance distance is essentially useless in preventing workspace crossover.  My suggestion is to make the workspace horizontal using CCSM > General Options > Desktop Size.

Answer (score 0):

cause this reason, I use `gnome flashback (metacity)` rather than
`gnome flashback (compiz)` for a long time.

but `metacity` has other problems.. >_<..

Answer (score -1):

I was very annoyed by the virtual desktops overlap "feature" of unity/compiz, too.

After many hours trying to deal with their various premature concepts, bugs and inefficiencies, (which still exist in Ubuntu 11.10), I gave them up and reverted to gnome2/metacity.

Metacity is a pretty lean and efficient window manager that separates workspaces.

Comment: Virtual desktops overlapped before in Ubuntu too, at least with compiz enabled.  But I've sinced moved to gnome shell, which gives you both an "accelerated" desktop as well as the non-overlapping workspaces.