# How to stop windows from moving past the edge of a workspace?

Tags: unity, window

I would like to stop windows from entering into neighbouring workspaces. I would like each window to be self contained inside the current workspace.

Also, how can I stop windows from going underneath the unity bar?

Thank you.

Comment: similar post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/50576/how-to-keep-a-window-from-overlapping-into-another-workspace

Answer (score 4):

This is currently a defect in Unity/Compiz. The best you can do is to enable edge stickiness. In ccsm (not installed by default because it's unstable as all get out), go to Window Management and enable "Snapping windows".

Make sure all 4 check boxes are checked and set resistance to 60 and attraction to 20.

This should *help* you keep your windows on a workstation.

However this is one of those taste things. Some people want things to span like this, others hate it. I personally am in the hate it group. I hope I am wrong, and that someone has a magic answer, but this is the best I have been able to find.

Just to make it clear, this won't stop the behavior, but it will make it a bit easier to manage.

Comment: I really hope I am wrong and some guru can come give us an awesome answer, I find this behavior very annoying and it gets in the way a lot.

Comment: Instead of installing ccsm, you can run [this script](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1367316/) to achieve the same result. Or manually copy paste those four lines of commands.

Comment: Thanks your suggestion worked great. I chose 75 and 50 for my own personal preference.

Comment: Nice ansewr, but it might be good if "ccsm" was spelled out and it was explained how to install it (sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager).

Comment: @Mahesh that script appears to no longer exist. Could you put it in an answer on this page?

Comment: is there a fix to this at 2017 ?

Comment: @Curious not really, seems to be a design decision. I stopped using Unity because of this. (and a few other things)