# Separate workspaces, not one huge screen

Tags: 14.04, workspaces, window

In Ubuntu 14.04 when the workspaces are enabled if a window is placed over the edge of the window it will also show in the next workspace. One messy workspace will basically ruin the workspaces next to it. Also if a window  sitting more than 50% over the workspace is maximized it will maximize on the other workspace causing it to disappear from the current workspace.

How can I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question. Apparently there is only a partial solution. Answer from : [How to stop windows from moving past the edge of a workspace?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218771/how-to-stop-windows-from-moving-past-the-edge-of-a-workspace)

> This is currently a defect in Unity/Compiz. The best you can do is to
>   enable edge stickiness. In ccsm (not installed by default because it's
>   unstable as all get out), go to Window Management and enable "Snapping
>   windows".

Install ccsm by `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

> Make sure all 4 check boxes are checked and set resistance to 60 and
>   attraction to 20.
>
> This should help you keep your windows on a workstation.
>
> However this is one of those taste things. Some people want things to
>   span like this, others hate it. I personally am in the hate it group.
>   I hope I am wrong, and that someone has a magic answer, but this is
>   the best I have been able to find.
>
> Just to make it clear, this won't stop the behavior, but it will make
>   it a bit easier to manage.